# Google Ad Mob with Kivy on Android

Tags: python-3.x, admob, kivy, kivy-language

Is there a way to integrate Google Ad Mob with Kivy 1.11.1 apps running on Android?

I came across a package called KivMob on GitHub. Will it work with the latest version of Google api(s)?

Can someone share a sample code? Is there any other way to achieve this?

Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can use admob ads. As you said you should use kivmob. I have used that in my apps and it is working well.
Sample code for banner ads.

```
from kivmob import KivMob, TestIds

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class BannerTest(App):
    """ Displays a banner ad at top of the screen.
    """

    def build(self):
        self.ads = KivMob(TestIds.APP)
        self.ads.new_banner(TestIds.BANNER, top_pos=True)
        self.ads.request_banner()
        self.ads.show_banner()
        return Label(text='Banner Ad Demo')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    BannerTest().run()
```

Then in your buildozer.spec file

```
requirements =  kivy, android, jnius, kivmob
...
android.permissions = INTERNET, ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
android.api = 28
android.minapi = 21
android.sdk = 24
android.ndk = 19b
android.gradle_dependencies = 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.2.0'
p4a.branch = master
# For test ads, use application ID ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713
android.meta_data = com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID={ADMOB_APP_ID_HERE}
```

For more information: http://kivmob.com/tutorials.html#